# Removing ModelErrors from ModelState once written to ValidationSummary()

Tags: asp.net-mvc, error-handling, model

I may be approaching this from the wrong angle entirely, but hopefully someone will know a way of acheiving what I'm after.

I reference a web service, which returns an ErrorInfo object. I add each returned error to the ModelState as a ModelError:

```
foreach(ErrorInfo error in serviceResponse)
    ModelState.AddModelError(error.AssociatedField, error.Description);
```

For errors which relate to a particular input field (using strongly-typed Views here), I get a nice inline error returned to Html.ValidationMessageFor(x), which is great.

The problem is that in addition to these input-related errors, there may also be more generate results.

What I'd LIKE to do is have these output in a list similar to Html.ValidationSummary() - however if I do this at the moment, it will also include the errors which have already been displayed inline against each input.

Is there an elegant way of just displaying all the errors which DON'T relate to a particular form input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a good enough solution for me, it doesn't print the individual error detail, but thats not important for the non-input related errors

```
Html.ValidationSummary(true, "Failed to login for some other reason")
```